# How to use subset sum algorithm in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the following array of objects:

```
const vehicles = [
    {
        name: "Truck 1",
        pallets: 15,
        capacity: 15
    },
    {
        name: "Truck 2",
        pallets: 12,
        capacity: 10
    },
    {
        name: "Truck 3",
        pallets: 20,
        capacity: 22
    },
    {
        name: "Truck 4",
        pallets: 24,
        capacity: 12
    }
]
```

I would like to get trucks as optimal as it's possible.
For example for 34 pallets that truck have to transport, algorithm should choose: Truck 4 (24 pallets) and Truck 2 (12 pallets). The number of pallets available in choose trucks should be equal or greater than demand. Additionally I have to also choose trucks that capacity is enough to carry a load. For example for 12 tones of cargo on 34 pallets algorithm should choose:

```
[
    {
        name: "Truck 4",
        pallets: 24,
        capacity: 12
    },
    {
        name: "Truck 2",
        pallets: 12,
        capacity: 10
    }
]
```

I've created some algorithm, but it's greedy algorithm and number of records in database causes that it takes too much time.
I will not present it here because it would be totally out of context. And the number of adjustments is too large for you to understand the problem.

Comment: This is a pretty classic algorithms question about combinations, but as to your specific use-case, how do you know how many tones of cargo are on a given pallet? Are they split evenly?

Comment: Yes, they are split evenly, but it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: @newmaster It actually matters a lot.  For example if they could be split unevenly, trucks 2 and 4 could take 36 pallets weighing 22 tonnes.  But split evenly, they can't.

Comment: The problem is about select those trucks that together will be able to take load with capacity and pallets demanding. It doesn't matter from an algorithmic point of view. It is about selecting objects such that the sum of the capacity property and the sum of the pallets property is greater than or equal to the given desired value.

Comment: So it's sounding like this a CS question rather than a real-world question, is that correct? That matters a lot to the solution you'll receive.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I didn't mentioned about it. We assume that each pallet has the same load

Comment: Also, how are you wanting to optimize this? Least number of trucks used? Or least amount of wasted capacity/pallet space? For example, if 2 trucks can carry the load, but they are barely full and have a ton of extra capacity, would you prefer that over 3 trucks carrying the load and each truck is more full?

Comment: The fewer trucks involved in the process, the better

Comment: Do you care if your two biggest trucks get used if your 2 smallest would have done the job?

Comment: If you don't care, there is a `O(n log(n))` solution where `n` is the number of trucks.  If you do care, there is a `O(n * m^2)` solution where `n` is the number of trucks and `m` is the number of pallets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `O(n * m^2)` solution.  And the reasoning behind it.

Assuming that the weight is split evenly by pallet, the first step is to figure out the weight per pallet, and then for each truck you have the maximum pallets that it can take.

In your example, a pallet weighs 6/17 tonnes which is about 0.36 tonnes.  Therefore we have that truck 1 can take `min(15, 15/(6/17)) = 15` pallets.  And likewise for the others.  (In this example, the number of pallets is the limit for all trucks.)

Next you need a cost function for using a truck.  For example we can say `1000 + unused_pallets + unused_weight`.  Assuming that no truck can carry more than 500 pallets or 500 tonnes of weight, this will use the smallest possible number of trucks, and then use the smallest trucks you can use.

Now what we do is called *dynamic programming*, we build up a data structure for the lowest cost way to take each number of pallets.  The answer at the end for the total number of pallets we want is our answer.  Here is code for that.

```
'use strict';

function cost (truck, pallets, capacity) {
    return 1000 + (truck.pallets - pallets) + (truck.capacity - capacity);
}

function optimize (trucks, pallets, weight) {
    var w = weight/pallets;

    // To begin, we can carry nothing for no weight.
    var best_path = [{cost: 0}];
    trucks.forEach(function (truck) {
        var max_pallets = Math.floor((Math.min(truck.pallets, truck.capacity/w)));
        // i is the number of pallets other trucks carry.
        // We count down so that there is no chance the solution there
        // has already used this truck.
        // BUG FIX: used to say max_pallets instead of pallets
        for (var i = pallets-1; 0 <= i; i--) {
            // j is the number of pallets that truck carries
            for (var j = 1; j <= Math.min(max_pallets, pallets - i); j++) {
                // Do we improve on i+j pallets by having truck carry i?
                if (best_path[i] == null) {
                    // Other trucks can't carry i
                    continue;
                }
                let prev_node = best_path[i];
                let this_solution = {
                    truck: truck,
                    pallets: j,
                    cost: prev_node.cost + cost(truck, j, w*j),
                    prev_node: prev_node
                };
                if (best_path[i+j] == null) {
                    best_path[i+j] = this_solution;
                }
                else if (this_solution.cost < best_path[i+j].cost) {
                    best_path[i+j] = this_solution;
                }
            }
        }
    });


    // The answer is a linked list.  Let's decode it for convenience.
    if (best_path[pallets] == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        let best = best_path[pallets];
        let answer = [];
        while (best.truck != null) {
            answer.unshift({
                truck: best.truck,
                pallets: best.pallets
            });
            best = best.prev_node;
        }
        return answer;
    }
}

const trucks = [
    {
        name: "Truck 1",
        pallets: 15,
        capacity: 15
    },
    {
        name: "Truck 2",
        pallets: 12,
        capacity: 10
    },
    {
        name: "Truck 3",
        pallets: 20,
        capacity: 22
    },
    {
        name: "Truck 4",
        pallets: 24,
        capacity: 12
    }
]

console.log(optimize(trucks, 34, 12));
```

Comment: I have a question, when i have too hight number of palletes or capacity, how can i do not match vehicles ? Because, now algo finds and matches many the sames trucks. Is it possible to avoid that ?

Comment: @newmaster Whoops, that's a pretty bad bug.  I just fixed it.  The fix involved switching `i` and `j` and counting down for one.  But the comments explain it.

Comment: There are some bugs, when i put float point number in trucks, for example for finding best set for 1 pallett with 1 weight and change Truck 1 for 1.5 pallett it doesn't shows me the best results or shows me other truck (worse). I detected this bug, because i was trying to use your algo in similar case, but not with palletes where the number are mainly integer, but with volume where float point numbers can appear.

Comment: @newmaster The algorithm assumes that it can count through pallets, so half a pallet doesn't make sense.  But I just added a `Math.floor(...)` to remove one floating point issue.  Does it work better now?

Comment: Hi, after long testing i found bug. If i put float point number in weight it doesn't work, returns me null.

Comment: It doesn't work, when i put too much number of palletes or too much weight it returns me null, even trucks can carry it.

Comment: It stops working (return null), when i put about more than 45 number of palletes and more than 41 weight.

Comment: @newmaster Big oops. I fixed it and marked where the fix was.  My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the combinations of all given objects and minimize the delta.

```js
function subsetSum(array, keys, sums) {

    function iter(index, temp, deltas) {
        if (deltas.every(d => d <= 0)) {
            if (
                !result ||                                        // first result
                result.deltas.reduce(add) < deltas.reduce(add) || // better delta
                temp.length < result.temp.length                  // less vehicles
            ) {
                result = { temp, deltas };
            }
            return;
        }
        if (index === array.length) return;
        iter(index + 1, temp.concat(array[index]), deltas.map((d, i) => d - array[index][keys[i]]));
        iter(index + 1, temp, deltas);
    }

    var result;
    iter(0, [], sums);
    return result && result.temp;
}

const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    vehicles = [{ name: "Truck 1", pallets: 15, capacity: 15 }, { name: "Truck 2", pallets: 12, capacity: 10 }, { name: "Truck 3", pallets: 20, capacity: 22 }, { name: "Truck 4", pallets: 24, capacity: 12 }],
    result = subsetSum(vehicles, ['pallets', 'capacity'], [34, 12]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is this ```O(n log(n))``` or ```O(n * m^2)``` ?

Comment: it is less than O(2^n - 1).

Comment: Means it better than ```O(n log(n))``` or ```O(n * m^2)``` ?

Comment: just insert 10 (for example) for n and calculate. it is the worst result.

Comment: @newmaster **Much** slower than both of those [here's a graph to illustrate](http://www.souravsengupta.com/cds2016/lectures/Complexity_Cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: return result ? result.temp : null; you should add this, because script catches error when number of pallets is too high.

Comment: So what is the recipe to create the best algo ?

Comment: you could add a check for the targets, eg less count of vehicles and exit the recursion if the length of `temp` is greater than the length of the already found result's length. or filter the goven data in advane, if it has to great values and keep only on which target value is the smallest of the greter ones.